# Compare current record's fields with fields inside a variable

Tags: awk

DISCLAIMER: I deleted my previous questions because I realized my logic was dumb and leading me nowhere.

I'm parsing a CSV as follows (field separated by tabs):

```
adrianascolaro  20200402    10:22:17    
adrianascolaro  20200402    16:03:59    
adrianascolaro  20200402        18:19:17
adrianascolaro  20200406    10:34:06    
adrianascolaro  20200406        16:31:15
adrianascolaro  20200406    17:10:58    
adrianascolaro  20200406        18:30:04
adrianascolaro  20200407    14:37:11    
adrianascolaro  20200407        16:00:37
adrianascolaro  20200407    22:56:50    
andersongoncalves   20200402    18:30:32    
andersongoncalves   20200402        19:08:34
andersongoncalves   20200402    19:12:47    
andersongoncalves   20200402        19:53:08
andersongoncalves   20200403    09:07:37    
andersongoncalves   20200403        09:10:57
andersongoncalves   20200403    13:01:45    
andersongoncalves   20200403    13:03:47    
andersongoncalves   20200403        13:03:53
andersongoncalves   20200403        15:37:38
```

I'm trying to find a way, using AWK, of:

1. finding consecutive lines where user, date and either first or last time (hours) are equal.
2. insert a string between matches using the fields of the next record shifting $3 and $4 positions.

So from the above sample I need to get this output:

```
adrianascolaro  20200402    10:22:17    
adrianascolaro  20200402        16:03:59
adrianascolaro  20200402    16:03:59    
adrianascolaro  20200402        18:19:17
adrianascolaro  20200406    10:34:06    
adrianascolaro  20200406        16:31:15
adrianascolaro  20200406    17:10:58    
adrianascolaro  20200406        18:30:04
adrianascolaro  20200407    14:37:11    
adrianascolaro  20200407        16:00:37
adrianascolaro  20200407    22:56:50    
andersongoncalves   20200402    18:30:32    
andersongoncalves   20200402        19:08:34
andersongoncalves   20200402    19:12:47    
andersongoncalves   20200402        19:53:08
andersongoncalves   20200403    09:07:37    
andersongoncalves   20200403        09:10:57
andersongoncalves   20200403    13:01:45    
andersongoncalves   20200403        13:03:47    
andersongoncalves   20200403    13:03:47    
andersongoncalves   20200403        13:03:53
andersongoncalves   20200403    15:37:38    
andersongoncalves   20200403        15:37:38
```

I'm having a hard time desiging a logic that can achieve that.
The furthest I went is:

For each $1, check if $1, $2 and $3 are equal on current and next; if they are, write between current and next $1,$2,"",$3 of the next line.
if they aren't, check if $1, $2 and $4 are equal on current and next; if they are, write between current and next $1,$2,$4,"" of the next line.

I have this, right now:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
{
for (i = 1; i<= NR; i++)
    {
    if (NR==1 || $1 == user && $2 == date && $3 == login)
        print $1,$2,"",$3;
    else
    if (NR==1 || $1 == user && $2 == date && $4 == logout)
        print $1,$2,$4,"";
    else
    exit 1;
{user=$1}{date=$2}{login=$3}{logout=$4}
}' sample.csv
```

I know I can `getline next` to store next record in the a variable.

I don't know how to use `getline next` inside my if-else-if and point my comparison to it.
I'm also lost on how I point awk to print the new information between current and next record.

The for loop is necessary because the way AWK seems to cycle through records when there's not a match AWK discards the culprit of the non-match and proceeds to evaluate the next record, instead of going record by record.

For example:

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
```

Say I want to print BINGO! if current matches with next, AWK would output THIS:

```
A
A
BINGO!
A
BINGO!
A
B
B
BINGO!
B
BINGO!
B
```

Instead of this:

```
A
BINGO!
A
BINGO!
A
BINGO!
A
B
BINGO!
B
BINGO!
B
BINGO!
B
```

Comment: Can we assume that the dates `$2` and times `$3` and `$4` are in ascending order for each group of `$1`?

Comment: Yes, they are all sorted. $1 is in alphabetical order, $2, $3 and $4 are in ascending order. I'm trying to achieve a normalization of data where there's no single instance of consecutive logins nor logouts for any day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input file I copied above has 4 white spaces instead of TABs for separating the fields. So I will invoke AWK with the field separator set to `"    "`. You will need to adapt the script according to your needs.

With the input you provided, I could get the desired output as far as I guessed the logic. Try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = "    "}
  ($1 == user) && ($2 == date) && login && $3 { print $1, $2, "", $3 }
  ($1 == user) && ($2 == date) && logout && $4 { print $1, $2, $4, "" }
  { print; user = $1; date = $2; login = $3; logout = $4 }    
' ranges.csv
```

My logic is to write an extra line in two cases:

1. When the previous line and the current line have both a login time, as far as the user and the date remain the same.
2. When the previous line and the current line have both a logout time, as far as the user and the date remain the same.

In all cases, match or no match, I print the current line (after the extra line if any) and I remember the previous values of the fields into variables for processing the next line.

The output I get is:

```
adrianascolaro    20200402    10:22:17    
adrianascolaro    20200402        16:03:59
adrianascolaro    20200402    16:03:59    
adrianascolaro    20200402        18:19:17
adrianascolaro    20200406    10:34:06    
adrianascolaro    20200406        16:31:15
adrianascolaro    20200406    17:10:58    
adrianascolaro    20200406        18:30:04
adrianascolaro    20200407    14:37:11    
adrianascolaro    20200407        16:00:37
adrianascolaro    20200407    22:56:50    
andersongoncalves    20200402    18:30:32    
andersongoncalves    20200402        19:08:34
andersongoncalves    20200402    19:12:47    
andersongoncalves    20200402        19:53:08
andersongoncalves    20200403    09:07:37    
andersongoncalves    20200403        09:10:57
andersongoncalves    20200403    13:01:45    
andersongoncalves    20200403        13:03:47
andersongoncalves    20200403    13:03:47    
andersongoncalves    20200403        13:03:53
andersongoncalves    20200403    15:37:38    
andersongoncalves    20200403        15:37:38
```

I suppose it is exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm speechless! Just... how? I did a biiiit of a modification to what you posted (adapted the four spaces to a tab, and the first print statement should have a $3 instead of $4. And it worked on the sample! Can you explain why you didn't need to store previous/next line nor use if/else keywords?

Comment: Wait a bit. There was a tipo indeed, but... the output was correct because I applied the script to the desired output, not to the input!!! I have to check if the solution is working with the correct input. Sorry about that.

Comment: OK, I am relieved: the script is working as intended.

Comment: I didn't need the `else` statement, because I identified that in each case, there was something common: print the current line and save the previous values. I took also advantage of the structure of the AWK language: three possible behaviours corresponding to resp. two specific conditions and a case that is always true.

Comment: Sir, I wish to get half as smart as that when I grow up. I've been struggling with that task for a darn week before asking here! My deepest appreciation for your help, sire.